# JavaNullPointerException after Login

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Hi,** so I'm developing my first app on android studio and I have a problem with my dashboard after I logged in I keep getting Java nullpointerexception. I somehow managed to make it work yesterday but it broked after I tried logging in with another user than the one I used and also it was showing the username of the old user that was logged in.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.licentabuna, PID: 2405
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.licentabuna/com.example.licentabuna.MainFrame}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getEmail()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.licentabuna.MainFrame.onCreate(MainFrame.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
```

Interface code:

```
package com.example.licentabuna;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainFrame extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    TextView firebasenameview;
    Button toast;

    private CardView addPacienti,searchPacienti,transfPacienti,checkPacienti;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_frame);
        firebasenameview = findViewById(R.id.firebase_nume); 

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String  finaluser=(user).getEmail();
        String result=finaluser.substring(0,finaluser.indexOf("@"));
        String resultemail=result.replace(".","");
        firebasenameview.setText("" + resultemail);
  /*      toast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainFrame.this,users.getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        });*/

        
        addPacienti=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.add_pacient);
        searchPacienti=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.cautare_pacient);
        transfPacienti=(CardView)findViewById(R.id.transf_pacient);

        
        addPacienti.setOnClickListener(this);
        searchPacienti.setOnClickListener(this);
        transfPacienti.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        Intent i;

        
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.add_pacient:i=new Intent(this,addPacienti.class);
              startActivity(i);
              break;
            case R.id.cautare_pacient:i=new Intent(this,cautarePacienti.class);
             startActivity(i);
             break;
//            case R.id.transf_pacient:i=new Intent(this,transfPacientiActivity.class);
//              startActivity(i);
//              break;
            default:break;
            }

    }
}
```

Login code:

```
package com.example.licentabuna;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private EditText mID;
    private EditText mPassword;
    private Button mloginBtn;
    private FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    int counter=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ID);
        mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pw);
        mloginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mloginBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {userLogin();});

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        fAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        mloginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.loginBtn:
                        startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainFrame.class));
                        userLogin();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void userLogin() {
        String id = mID.getText().toString().trim();
        String pass = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();


        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(id)) {
            mID.setError("Adaugati emailul dvs");
            mID.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(id).matches()) {
            mID.setError("Adauga-ti o adresa valida de email");
            mID.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) {
            mPassword.setError("Adaugati parola");
            mPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (pass.length() < 6) {
            mPassword.setError("Parola trebuia sa aiba 6 sau mai multe caractere");
            mPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        fAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(id,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                if(user.isEmailVerified()){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this,MainFrame.class));
                }else{
                    user.sendEmailVerification();
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Verifica-ti emailul pentru verificare",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    //redirect spre profil user
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainFrame.class));

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Verifica-ti-va datele de autentificare",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context=".MainFrame">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firebase_nume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="137dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="197dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="Salut,"
        android:textColor="#020202"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/firebase_nume"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:columnCount="2">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/add_pacient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#39ECC8"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_add" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Adaugare Pacient"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cautare_pacient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_search" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cautare Pacient"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/transf_pacient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_stat_transf" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Transfer Pacient"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/stergere_pacient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_photo_camera_24" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WORK IN PROGRESS"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/logout_pacient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_photo_camera_24" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="NUME.EXE"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/afisare_pacient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_200"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_photo_camera_24" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="INCA E"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    </GridLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background1"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="#E30F0F"
        android:textSize="38sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ID"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="148dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:background="#040404"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_id"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:hint="id"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FAF9F9"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Pw"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#040404"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:hint="password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FAF9F9"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ID"
        android:autofillHints="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
        android:text="login"
        app:backgroundTint="#E30F0F"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Pw" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/background1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginBtn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Find you `logcat` and add the entire exception to your question.

Comment: The stacktrace seems pretty clear: `getCurrentUser` returned `null` (just like the documentation says it will if no user is signed in), but you assumed that it would never returned `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to come from here:

```
final FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
String  finaluser=(user).getEmail();
```

It looks like `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` returns `null`, which then makes the `(user).getEmail()` fail.

If you're not sure that the user is signed in, you can check whether it is by adding a check:

```
final FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    String  finaluser=(user).getEmail();
    ...
```

If you think the user should be signed in, then it could be that this code runs before Firebase has established that fact. If that's the case, consider [using an auth state listener](https://gist.github.com/puf/9818068b3be173c40cdcf56d2cc59029) to ensure your code only runs after the user's sign-in state has been established.